# Auto height cell after add text

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I have tableView and when i type i want auto height cell. But i don't know how to fix it. My first idea was:

```
self.chatTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text = new_char
self.chatTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.sizeToFit()
self.chatTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
```

When i have this line with `.sizeToFit()` my result looks like this:
[image: first result]
But when i comment this line:

```
self.chatTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text = new_char
self.chatTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
```

My result looks this:
[image: econd result]

Is any way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the height of your `UITableViewCell` directly. But the height of the cell is handled in the `UITableView`. To make this work you have to do two things:

**1. Use self sizing cells:**

Just add this two lines of code to your `viewDidLoad`method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40
    }
```

The `estimatedRowHeight` is only used to calculate the scroll bar size and position so you just put the normal expected height of your cells here.

**2. Reload the cell after you changed the text**

After you changed the text of your cell's label, you have to tell the `UITableView` to reload this cell so that its height gets adjusted. You do this by calling this method:

```
func addSomeText() {
    // add the text to your data source

    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Obviously the indexPath is your cell's indexPath.

**One important thing**: You cannot add the new text directly to the cell. Instead you have to add it to your `dataSource`. Otherwise the text will be gone after the reload, because the cell gets its text from the `dataSource` when it is dequeued.

Comment: i can add text directly to cell :)

Comment: ok, then you are adding the text differently than I did. Even better ;-)